# Lack of a basis for a Dual Space of an infinite dimensional vector space

Tags: linear-algebra, dual-spaces

I understand that the dual basis of a finite dimensional vector space is a basis for the dual space. Conceptually, I understand that this is not true in the infinite dimensional case, but my understanding is that if I begin calculating a “basis” as if I were seeking a dual basis in the finite case (defined in the usual way using the Kronecker symbol), the elements should still be linearly independent. Is this correct? Could someone demonstrate why?

Comment: An infinite set $S$ of vectors is linearly independent if and only if every finite subset of $S$ is linearly independent. This answer your question?

Comment: I’m sorry but I’m still not following. Could you go into a bit more detail?

Answer (score 1):

The dual space consists of *continuous* functionals. You can use Zorn's lemma to construct a "Hamel basis" $H$ for any vector space $V$. Then you can define, for $h\in H$, the dual element $h^*$ in the same way you define it for finite-dimensional vector spaces. But $h^*$ generally won't be continuous.

To see an example that looks like the finite dimensional case, you can read about Hilbert spaces. The basic example of a Hilbert space is $\ell^2$, the set of complex sequences $c$ such that $\sum_n |c_n|^2 < \infty$.
We say that $\ell^2$ has a "basis" consisting of the sequences
$e_1 = (1, 0, 0, 0, \ldots)$,
$e_2 = (0, 1, 0, 0, \ldots)$, et cetera.
But this is not a Hamel basis. Its linear combinations are merely dense in $\ell^2$.